# Properly setting up vscode for C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

The recommended Microsoft C/C++ extension for VSCode works great for C++ but fails at some places with C giving false errors. Here's one I have found:

[image]

```c
void f(int a,int b, int arr[][b]);
```

This is valid C code and yet it says there's an error.
So how do I properly set up my intellisense to account for such nuances?

Comment: That's a C++ warning. It's not allowed in C++. What's the extension of this file and what editing mode are you in?

Comment: @tadman its a .c file. wdym what editing mode i am in? and yes, thats the point. its a c++ warning in a .c file

Comment: That's a very odd function signature to write in the first place. What I mean is does the editor show this as C code, or C++ code?

Comment: @tadman it says c in the bottom right and thats it. im using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) for the intellisense.

Comment: Perhaps try the [clangd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) extension instead